# Unable to obtain moments using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to calculate the moments of a vector `x = np.random.normal(0,1,[1,500])`. When I do `mean, std = tf.nn.moments(x,axes=[0])`, it throws this error:

```
File "/tmp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py", line 830, in moments
y = math_ops.cast(x, dtypes.float32) if x.dtype == dtypes.float16 else x
TypeError: data type not understood
```

I am using `tensorflow==0.11.0`. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the documentation for [tf.nn.moments](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn/normalization#moments), the input x must be a Tensor.

You should use something like the following:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None,500])
mean, std = tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[0])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sample_mean, sample_std = sess.run([mean, std],
    feed_dict={x: np.random.normal(0,1,[1,500])})
```

Note: This particular calculation does not make much sense, since there is only one data value. You may want to either increase the shape to something like [32, 500], or more likely change the axes from [0] to [1].

Regardless, the calculation will complete without errors, despite the calculated standard deviation being equal to 0, because the moments are calculated along an axis with one dimension.

Comment: Isn't the variance just the standard deviation squared? i.e. variance = tf.square(std)